# Use Move-Item in PowerShell to append Hostname and date to file name

Tags: powershell

Complete PowerShell newbie so please forgive me as I might mess up what I am asking.

I have a file called `debug.log`, I need to rename it and move it.

I know I can do that with Move-Item, but I would like to append the Hostname to the front of the file name and the date stamp to the end.

For example:
In: `C:\Temp\debug.log`
Out: `\\\sharename\MyHostdebug20201006.log`

The files will go through a log parse after they get copied to the share, and the HostName and Date stamp are import to my tracking of which logs get processed. I have to do this for 8 separate servers on a monthly basis. I plan on setting this up as a Windows Schedule Task when it is completed.

Comment: Where is the script running? On the host or elsewhere? $env:ComputerName holds the hostname of the current host.

Comment: It will run on each individual host, until I can figure out how to do this more efficiently. Just getting the Hostname and date onto the file will handle my immediate goals. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7) and, as mentioned by @Scepticalist above, $env:ComputerName you can create a string variable which you can pass into your [Move-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7) as the destination:

```
$timestamp = get-date -Format yyyyMMdd
$newPath = "\\sharename\" + $env:computername + "debug" + $timestamp + ".log"
```